# SPARQL: Split one variable by object type

Tags: sparql, rdf

I've some RDF data which looks something like this:

```
WatchObject -subclassOf-> Accessory
BagObject -subclassOf-> Accessory
Person -hasAccessory-> Accessory
```

Where WatchObject and BagObject are both subclasses of "Accessory", which has the relation has(is)Accessory(of) with Person.

I would like to query it now to get a persons watches and bags in seperate variables. So I thought of something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?watch ?bag
WHERE {
    ?person rdf:type x:Person .
    ?person x:hasAccessory ?bag^^x:BagObject .
    ?person x:hasAccessory ?watch^^x:WatchObject .
}
```

Is it possible to express something like this in a SPARQL query? Another question would be if it's reasonable to model my data like this, or would it be better to add two more ObjectProperties like this?

```
WatchObject -subclassOf-> Accessory
BagObject -subclassOf-> Accessory
Person -hasAccessory-> Accessory
Person -hasWatch-> WatchObject
Person -hasBag-> BagObject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add triples specifying a type of the ?bag and ?watch variables, just like you specified a type for the ?person variable:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?watch ?bag {
    ?person a x:Person .
    ?person x:hasAccessory ?bag .
    ?bag a x:BagObject .
    ?person x:hasAccessory ?watch .
    ?watch a x:WatchObject .
}
```

Note that that will get you the cross product of bags and watches;  i.e., you'll get each combination of a person's bags and watches.  Also, it requires that the person have at least one bag and at least one watch, otherwise the query won't match.  You might look into **optional** to see how to make these optional.

> Another question would be if it's reasonable to model my data like
>   this, or would it be better to add two more ObjectProperties like
>   this?
>
> ```
> WatchObject -subclassOf-> Accessory
> BagObject -subclassOf-> Accessory
> Person -hasAccessory-> Accessory
> Person -hasWatch-> WatchObject
> Person -hasBag-> BagObject
> ```

You could do this, too.  If you do, then it might also be good to add the triples:

```
hasWatch rdfs:subPropertyOf hasAccessory
hasBag   rdfs:subPropertyOf hasAccessory
```

Then, if you have inference enabled, or you adjust your query a little bit, then you can still retrieve things with just the one hasAccessory property.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried the approach with the cross product but it slows down my querys to much. I ended up creating the additional hasWatch / hasBag properties as subproperties of hasAccessory, as you suggested.

Comment: Ok,  you don't have to get the cross product, though.  You could still use something like the first approach.